# Python Identity operators with variables and datastructures

Tags: python, identity-operator

I have the following code:

```
a = []
b = a
```

when I compile the following code I get this:

```
print(b is a) --> True
print(b is []) --> False
```

if b = a then shouldn't `b is []` return `True`?

Comment: `is` means referential equality, so that both things refer to the *same* object, two separate lists are *not* the same object.

Comment: No, not at all. Equality is not identity

Comment: Whether a literal produces a new object or refers to an existing object is basically an implementation detail. Don't use `is` with literals.

Comment: I should say, for *immutable* values it is an implementation detail. For mutable values, caching a value will cause problems.

Comment: Not all `[]` are the same object.  `[]` is just an empty list, which can be constructed in many ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try that:

```
    a = []
b = a


print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(id([]))
```

And you will see that a and b refers to the same object, while next [] is a different one. Check `if b` to see if b is not empty list